# Wordpress comment feed order

Tags: wordpress, rss, comments, feed

By default, wordpress adds comments in an order of oldest to newset into comments feed.

But, there is a problem. For example, This is Comments order on the website:

> [1_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]
>
> ////[4_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__** ]
>
> [2_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]
>
> [3_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]
>
> [5_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]

Which the 4th comment is a response to the first comment.

But in feed, I'll give this order:

> [1_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]
>
> [2_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]
>
> [3_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]
>
> [4_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]
>
> [5_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]

Isn't there any way to publish answers of a comment, just after that comment?

I want my comments feed to be something like this:

> [1_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]
>
> [4_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]
>
> [2_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]
>
> [3_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]
>
> [5_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** ]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to hook into pre_get_posts, check if it's the feed, and modify the query accordingly.